# How to Update Node Value into Existing XML file Using Flash AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, urlrequest

I have a Xml File having the values, I am using Flash **AIR** application with Action Script3,

```
<Home>
  <Name>John</Name >
  <RollNo>102</RollNo >
  <Age>25</Age >
  <Mark>70</Mark >
</Home >
```

For read the xml file I used the

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = null;
var xmlData:XML = new XML();
xmlLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadingXMLData);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("Details.xml"));

function LoadingXMLData(e:Event):void
{
    xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
    ParseXML(xmlData);
}

function ParseXML(configData:XML):void 
{
    trace("XML Data : " + configData);
}
```

I want to update a particular node value. 
How can I update the value in the existing XML file.

for update the value i have tried

```
xmlData.replace(xmlData.hostName,"Helooon");
trace("Updated XML Data : " + xmlData);
```

How to write these in to the existing XML file.

Comment: You want to write/update a file on the users machine?  Are you using AIR?  If so you can do it easily enough assuming the app has permission.   If not, the best you can do is open a save file prompt and instruct the user to save over top of the existing file.

Comment: @LDMS: Yes I am using AIR. I want to update a value in the existing xml file

Comment: Good, use the `File` and `FileStream` classes.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html.    You can read the file using the file class too instead of URLLoader.   Here is an example: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/xml_prefs.html

Answer (score 0):

To save the XML back to a file you have to use [`FileReference.save()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save()) in the Flash Player, or [`File`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) with [`FileStream.writeUTFBytes()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#writeUTFBytes()) in AIR.

**EDIT:** I see your comment that you are using AIR, so you can use the `File` class. Here's a quick example:

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("Details.xml");
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeUTFBytes(xmlData);
stream.close();
```

Note that because the XML is parsed and re-encoded, formatting may change. You can control the formatting output using [`XML` static formatting properties](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#propertySummary).